# How to set border to left or top component of JSplitPane in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I want to set Border to the left and right of the JSplitpane , so what i found is just dorder  to entire JSplitpane and the divider , any suggestion ?

### [image]

this is the code i use :

```
split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, new LeftPanelInfos(),
    SetVerticalSplitPane());
split.setResizeWeight(0.30);
split.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
split.setEnabled(false);
split.setDividerSize(10);
System.out.println(this.getSize());

BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ((BasicSplitPaneUI)split.getUI()).getDivider();
divider.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));  

this.getContentPane().add(split);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:
myComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 5, Color.Black));

You can checkout the Java Tutorial "How to Use Borders" - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html for more examples, or just read the API for Borders and BorderFactory.

Comment: i know how to set the border to component , but what i can't do is the border to the half part of Jsplitpane ie i want something like this jSplitPane.getleftcomponent().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.Black))

Comment: ok - so why wouldn't you do _exactly_ that? there is a method for getting the left component, or you could set up the border directly on the component. If you want this to happen on changes to the component than you probably want to either define a listener for that or a super class based on JSplitPane.

Comment: i want that the part of jsplitpane will be clearly separated by these border , so i have two part the left and right side and i want to set the border to them , the problem when i get the left component and can't set the border because there is no method to do this

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what you mean - but any JComponent has a "setBorder" method. Maybe your left component is not a JComponent?

Comment: i know that the component accept a border and i know how to set it , the problem for me that i can't fount a method to set border to each part of JSplitPane (ie the left and the right or the top and bottom ) see the idited post , i added a picture as example